# Swatches panel not adding basic RGB, appearing in a new window Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cs6, swatches

When I go to add a swatch group to the swatches panel say basic RGB it opens it in a new window?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply how Illustrator works. It doesn't add swatches to the Swatches Panel when opening external libraries.

If you want them all in the Swatches Panel, highlight the swatches in the Basic RGB Panel, and drag them to the Swatches Panel.